# Error using \string

Tags: conditionals, strings

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\string\iftrue}

%% \texttt =\long macro:
%% #1->\ifmmode
%%       \nfss@text{\ttfamily#1}
%%     \else
%%       \hmode@bgroup\text@command{#1}\ttfamily\check@icl#1\check@icr\expandafter\egroup
%%     \fi

\end{document}
```

Processing this minimal example with `pdflatex` results in a rather nasty `Incomplete \ifmmode` error during the expansion of `\texttt{\string\iftrue}`. It seems to me that `\string` does not totally prevent TeX from taking account of `\iftrue` as a conditional. (The same is true for `\detokenize`, by the way.)

Can anybody explain what is precisely going on?

---

**Addendum:** Note that the error would disappear if `\texttt` stored its argument in an auxiliary macro before processing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
\iffalse
\string\iftrue
\fi
```

On seeing the `\iffalse` TeX scans ahead matching tokens with definitions 
`\if` (or the other primitive if tokens such as `\ifx` `\iftrue` etc) `\else` and `\fi` to get to a matching `\fi` when normal operation re-starts. In particular it does *not* execute any assignments or expand any tokens. So `\string` is simply skipped over but the inner `\iftrue` is seen so the `\fi` matches the `\iftrue` and things go wrong.

Depending what you want to do

```
\iffalse
 \textbackslash iftrue
\fi
```

or

```
\iffalse
\csname iftrue\endcsname
\fi
```

or

```
\iffalse
\expandafter\string\csname iftrue\endcsname
\fi
```

are all safe. (Or similarly and more usefully perhaps the same with `\iftrue` as the first token.)

Comment: OK, I think I understand: The key point is that TeX parses conditionals in a totally context-free manner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bear in mind that TeX is a macro expansion language. Thus

```
\texttt{\string\iftrue}
```

expands the definition of `\texttt` with an argument containing two tokens, `\string` and `\iftrue`. That leads to

```
\ifmmode
  \nfss@text{\ttfamily\string\iftrue}
\else
  \hmode@bgroup
    \text@command{\string\iftrue}%
    \ttfamily
    \check@icl\string\iftrue\check@icr
  \expandafter\egroup
\fi
```

(formatting mine). TeX then scans the conditional, finds more tokens which start `\if...` statements than end them, and complains.

What you presumably want to do is pass the string `\iftrue` to `\texttt`:

```
\expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\string\iftrue}
```

Comment: Or the easier ``\texttt{\char`\\iftrue}``.

Comment: @egreg That's not a string: `iftrue` is made of catcode 11 tokens :-)

Comment: (Of course, that might be important in some contexts, but not here)

Comment: @JosephWright: Expanding the argument in advance is definitely a useful remedy. Is there, actually, a more general argument processor capable of expanding an arbitrary brace-delimited argument such as `{text \string\iftrue text}`?

Comment: @mhp Depending on the context, you could either `\edef` everything into a temporary variable or use `\romannumeral` to force expansion; the latter method is itself expandable.

Comment: @JosephWright: But the ``\romannumeral-`\0`` trick can’t be directly applied to an argument such as `{text \string\iftrue text}`, can it?

Comment: @mhp Should be fine, although again will depend on context. For example, ``\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1 }}`` works with `\string\iftrue` but will fail with `text \string\iftrue text` as a loop is needed to deal with multiple non-expandable tokens. (I posted an answer to a question about that once.) I'd probably use `\edef` or better `\protected@edef` in the case you outline as `\texttt` is not expandable anyway.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks! Probably, I’ll try something like `\newcommand*{\expandarg}[1]{\protected@edef\temp{\protect#1}\temp}`.